# Internal error: 'http://localhost:63342/epimss_polymer_app/web/index.dart': malformed type: line 37 pos 42465: type 'prefix16.property' is not loaded

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have run into this problem for the second time without having a clue as to why it is occurring.

My application just started running with no output in normal mode and in debug mode I get the following

```
    Internal error: 'http://localhost:63342/epimss_polymer_app/web/index.dart': malformed type: line 37 pos 42465: type 'prefix16.property' is not loaded
final _data = {const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(): new r.ReflectorData(<m.ClassMirror>[new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"PolymerMixin", r"polymer.src.common.polymer_js_proxy.PolymerMixin", 519, 0, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const <int>[], const <int>[], const <int>[], -1, {} ....
```

The entire output is in the attached file:
The output seems pretty unhelpful to me with no indication as to what file or line the issue occurred.

I am using 1.13.0-dev.7.3 (ref ec143d4) and WebStorm 11 EAP (current EAP).

I have been stuck for the last 4 days going over my code without any success.

Can't seem to attach the entire file output - previously I could attach a file - where is the link now?

Comment: Please try to create a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That poses a problem Gunter because I have no clue where the problem lies. I have looked through output and find nothing familiar to cross-reference. This problem is associated with polymer1.0-rc-x as I have not seen any such problem previously. I have just began to port pre-1.0 polymer to 1.x. Not a lot of code is present as yet. How do I attached the zip?

Comment: Please create a GitHub repo and post the link. "Not a lot of code" is a good thing. Still try to remove as much as possible but the error still needs to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this with this property:

```
@property(observer: 'selectedChanged')
bool selected;

@reflectable
selectedChanged(oldVal, newVal) {
  print(newVal);
}
```

which should actually be

```
@Property(observer: 'selectedChanged')
```

(with a capital `@P...`)

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24751